# Exporting data in XML file format from ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, xml

Is it possible to export shapefiles or rasters in XML file format from ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: See
[A quick tour of exporting data](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n00000037000000).

Comment: This is really a question that a quick search on google would have easily resolved.

Comment: Come on GIS.SE community! 5 downvotes in 2 hours for a question that is neither poorly written nor off-topic? By piling on downvotes all we do is show Charly and all new-comers that this isn't a very friendly and open community. From SE: "Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing." If it's spam or a duplicate flag it for a moderator. If the question is 'wrong' (and I don't know how a question can be) then leave a comment or edit it. Erica and lcoursey already did the job here (good for them); why pile on the downvote further?

Comment: @WhiteboxDev Well, it might not be considered reason enough for downvoting, but our [Help](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) also states that one should *thoroughly search for an answer before asking   [a] question*.

Comment: @Martin I completely agree with you, but which do you think drove the point home better, lcoursey's excellent comment or the five downvotes? My guess is that the downvote pile-on did nothing more than tell Charly we don't like their questions and we'll be lucky to see them here again. It's the equivalent to a group gathering around the school-yard bully as he picks on the little guy. The comment on the other hand will have the effect of improving any future questions. I'm talking about building a more inclusive community here and downvotes to excess don't help with that.

Comment: @lcoursey I usually do that quick search on google before posting a new question. I would assure that it has been so also at this time, unless I have been answering in other threads and have straightaway asked a new question. I am sure I have looked at the suggested existing threads when filling in the subject and found nothing related. I don't know if I am missing something, I am rather a newbie in this forum. Anyway, I can assure I appreciate the help and time of the people from this forum, and I have the higher respect for this matter. Apologies if it has seemed the opposite.

Comment: @Charly Charly, you don't need to thank me; pay it forward by helping out some newcomers yourself. Upvote them when they need it and help them to form stronger, more answerable questions through comments and editing.

Comment: I would do it if I can contribute: I read other post topics, by now I feel I am still a beginner, I hope I soon cease to be like an observer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Data needs to located in a geodatabase in order to export to XML. You can do this manually, or use the tool [Export XML Workspace Document (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000015s000000).  For the manual approach, simply right-click the featureclass or raster dataset within the file geodatabase > Export > XML Workspace Document.

[image]

Which then brings up the following GUI, where you can specify the export

[image]

Comment: ...Well thought out and articulated answers, now that does help build a better community!

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Data Interoperability extension (paid license) you can export vector data (i.e. shapefiles) to the [GML simple features](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003700000004000000) (GML-SF) xml profile.

A free and open source option is to use the [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) command-line utility from the [GDAL/OGR project](https://gdal.org/). i.e. `ogr2ogr -f GML somevectors.gml somevectors.shp`.  You can install GDAL/OGR from the [GIS Internals](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php) site or by using the [OSGEO4W installer](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/).