# Extracting metadata from shapefile in FME?

Tags: shapefile, fme-form, metadata

Does anyone know how to extract metadata information from a shapefile in FME?

To be exact, i want to extract the schema (data structure) of the data such as the field names, etc. from a shapefile and export as a xml or any format.

Example, if i have a shapefile named 'Road', i want to extract its field names like road name, road length etc and export it in xml preferably rather than viewing the field names of the shapefile in a datainspector.

Comment: What type of metadata?  Can you edit your question to include exactly what you want to do and what you've tried?

Comment: If any format is acceptable, why not just use the .dbf that accompanies the .shp file?

Comment: Well sure.Could you suggest how to export a field names alone from a dbf to xml

Comment: If you are coding this in .NET, you could load up the DBF file as a DataTable, which has built in methods for table schema.

Comment: Have you tried using the ["Schema (Any Format)"](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_ReadersWriters/Default.htm#schema/schema.htm) reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple options:

[image: Workbench]

Static: Schema (Any Format) Reader

[image: SchemaReaderParameters]

Dynamic: FeatureReader Transformer
Use Creator to initiate proces.
Define folder in Dataset.
Choose Schema Features in Schema/Data Features.
Connect  output port.

[image: FeatureReaderParameters]

Result:

```
attribute{0}.fme_data_type (string) fme_varchar(10)
attribute{0}.name (string)  CTE
attribute{0}.native_data_type (string)  char(10)
attribute{1}.fme_data_type (string) fme_varchar(50)
attribute{1}.name (string)  THEMA
attribute{1}.native_data_type (string)  char(50)
attribute{2}.fme_data_type (string) fme_varchar(50)
attribute{2}.name (string)  THEMB
attribute{2}.native_data_type (string)  char(50)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to create schema document(*.xsd) out of the shapefile. You can do this in Arcmap 10.1 *[Exporting data in xml file format](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115278/exporting-data-in-xml-file-format-from-arcgis-for-desktop)*, which can export any feature or raster class to xml document. From there you can convert it into *.xsd document with the help of several online convertors like [FreeFormatter.com](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html) and [xmlgrid.net](http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html).

In Arcmap, add shapefiles into geodatabase and then run the conversion tool.